# Application getting crashed on setting the vocabulary for carName using Siri Kit

Tags: ios11, sirikit, xcode9.3

I am trying to develop an application using SiriKit to get the car door lock status and set the same from Siri. I followed this blog https://www.appcoda.com/sirikit-introduction/ and did all the setup replacing the **INStartWorkoutIntent** with **INGetCarLockStatusIntent**.

But when i try to set the vocabulary for carName, the application is getting crashed with following exception,

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to provide vocabulary of type INVocabularyStringTypeCarName by an app that does not handle any intents that could use that type of vocabulary'**

The source code that i am using to set the vocabulary is,

```
INPreferences.requestSiriAuthorization { (status) in

  }      
INVocabulary.shared().setVocabularyStrings(["benz", "bmw", "audi"], of: .carName)
```

In **AppDelegate**, i have added the following method,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    guard let intent = userActivity.interaction?.intent as? INGetCarLockStatusIntent else {
        print("AppDelegate: Start Workout Intent - FALSE")
        return false
    }
    print("AppDelegate: Start Workout Intent - TRUE")
    print(intent)
    return true
}
```

Also created the extension for intent handler and implemented **INSetCarLockStatusIntentHandling**, **INGetCarLockStatusIntentHandling** protocols. I am getting this issue when i try to run it in iPhone 10.

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope. I couldn't fix it. But i am not sure whether it is working now or not. Didn't had the time to test.

Answer (score 0):

Check, if in TARGETS of your project in Build Phases->Embed App Extensions added your Siri Extension. Maybe if you replace the INStartWorkoutIntent with INGetCarLockStatusIntent, old INStartWorkoutIntent remained there.

My crash fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. Make sure your extension's ***Deployment Target*** is set to appropriate iOS version. Creating an extension with the latest Xcode (at the moment 10.1) will set the ***Deployment Target*** to **12.1** and thus cause crash when run on **iOS 10**. So you should change it to your desired minimum.